# Android: TextInputLayouts always have an error icon

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have noticed that since a few days, all my TextInputLayouts have the "error exclamation point" always enabled. I haven't changed anything about those TextInputLayouts for a long time, so I really don't understand what is happening.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

Do you have have any idea what could be the source of this issue? Did something recently changed with the TextInputLayouts?

Thank you very much in advance

### EDIT

Here is the related code:
The .xml file is really simple. It's a list of TextInputLayouts and EditTexts like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_margin">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/txtAddressTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/PROFILE_SCREEN_ADDRESS_INPUT_TITLE"
        android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Also, there **absolutely no mention of setError()** in my Kotlin code.

Comment: `TextInputLayout`'s error is a `TextView` underneath the `EditText`. That looks like `setError()` called directly on the `EditText`s, rather than the `TextInputLayout`s.

Comment: You should post the controlling code

Comment: In Kotlin, it would just be `editText.error = ...`.

Comment: @MikeM. I don't use "editText.error".
Also, the red exclamation points appear in the .xml preview. As if was enabled by default O_o

Comment: So, it's a tool issue? Not happening on your device after installing?

Comment: @rafid059 Sadly, it's also happening on my devices

Comment: Please put together a [mcve].

Comment: I think the default behaviour is showing that icon when error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**
It looks like it's fixed with `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04`.

---

Ho, I found the issue. I actually updated the version of the Material library from version `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08` to `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09`.

Google changed the behaviour of Text Field (see here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha09):

Text Field:

- Adding option to set TextInputLayout icons to be not checkable (6a88f2b)
- Implementing error icon for text fields (3f73804)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this without having to downgrade to 1.1.0-alpha08? And if so, what changes did you make?

Comment: I'm using `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'` Still haing this issue

Answer (score 56):

You can try this. But It will permanently remove the error Icon. If you want to show it again you have do it programmatically.

```
app:errorIconDrawable="@null"
```

Comment: Attention. This property must be set on the layout, not on the edit text itself.